# Why does Tor unexpectedly exit every time I open it?

Tags: users, browser, tor, ownership, tor-browser

Every time I try to run tor it unexpectedly exits and I get this in my terminal:

```
(process:28965): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Aug 04 01:38:35.833 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.21 (git-f5def645adfb32be) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1g.
Aug 04 01:38:35.833 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Aug 04 01:38:35.834 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults".
Aug 04 01:38:35.834 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor/torrc".
Aug 04 01:38:35.836 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9151
Aug 04 01:38:35.837 [notice] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
Aug 04 01:38:35.837 [warn] /usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor is not owned by this user (brody, 1000) but by root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Aug 04 01:38:35.837 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't access/create private data directory "/usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor"
Aug 04 01:38:35.837 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Tor Browser exited cleanly.

Comment: The Tor Browser should probably be installed in your home folder and owned by you, but instead it is installed globally and owned by root. How did you install it, and exactly what command or commands are running to attempt to launch it?

Answer (score 0):

> Aug 04 01:38:35.837 [warn] /usr/bin/tor-browser/Data/Tor is not owned by this user (brody, 1000) but by root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?

tells us what we need to know. The directory that the file is trying to write to is owned by root, and your privileges aren't sufficient. If you installed tor through the apt repository, that would probably be why.

Download the latest tor tarball from https://www.torproject.org/ and extract the contents, from there go into a terminal window, navigate to the directory you extracted and type `chmod +x start-tor-browser.sh` (may not be the exact file name, but I digress).

Then type `./start-tor-browser.sh` to start the browser. It should work from there.